# Javascript new Date(), compare confuse

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain this unexpected behavior?

```js
console.log(new Date() == new Date()); // false
console.log(new Date() >= new Date()); // true
console.log(new Date() <= new Date()); // true
```

Comment: Those `Date`s may not necessarily be the same since they're created separately. What are the results if you create 1 at the top and then do the comparisons on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` comparator compares the object references, and two different objects will **never** be equal.

The relational comparators, however, will compare the numeric values of the dates (the underlying timestamps). Thus if you tried

```
new Date().getTime() == new Date().getTime()
```

you'd get `true`.  In this case, the `=` part of the `>=` and `<=` operators makes the statements true (as in the example above).

Comment: Then why both the second line and third line prints `true`?

Comment: @armnotstrong Because both objects are created close enough together to represent the same time, so the `=` part of `<=` and `>=` matches.

Comment: silly me, forgot the `=` part

Answer (score 3):

The first is comparing equality of 2 different objects.

The `>=` and `<=` will first coerce the Date objects to Number

Simplified resultant example:

```
{} == {} // false    
41765490 <= 41765490 // true
41765490 >= 41765490 // true
```

For the first case of `==` you can also force the coersion to number doing:

```
+new Date() == +new Date() // true (assuming no lag between creating both)
```

Answer (score 0):

Date() is object.

`new Date()` will generate an object(let's call it a)

and `== new Date()` will generate another object(call it b)

so object a == object b will return false.

But `>=` or `<=` will compare the value of the objects, it will return true as long as the value is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you compare dates i Javascript.

(date1.getTime() === date2.getTime())

```js
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
console.log(date1.getTime() === date2.getTime()); // true
 console.log(date1 >= date2); // true
 console.log(date1 <= date2); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled and I found the response in Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41980287/2520689

As it said:

> Using instead a constructor as new Date(), each instance is unique
>   (the two instances of the same constructor are still different to
>   each-other), this is the reason why they are not equal when compared.